# Google webmasters 404 for a URL path starting with /facebook.com/

Tags: google-search-console

We've been having some problems with Google Webmasters Tools lately. Google's returning 404 on some of our articles. Can you anyone please explain why Google Webmasters Tools returns this error and how to fix it?

```
[POSTURLHERE]/facebook.com/thetunistimes?PHPSESSID=te69ddda6ct3g1dfk898fiq9c3
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

There are likely two problems on your site.

1. You are incorrectly linking to facebook from your article.

   - Your link is `facebook.com/thetunistimes`
   - But should be `http://facebook.com/thetunistimes` (include the `http://`)
2. PHP is putting session ids on your links (which is very bad for SEO).  Here are some instructions from removing them: http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=447402.0

> Put below two lines in your .htaccess file

```
php_value session.use_only_cookies 1
php_value session.use_trans_sid
```

And then put a rule in to strip session ids off of URLs with 301 redirects.